ffmpeg on ElementaryOS. Poor video quality with screen recording
I am running ElementaryOS 7.1 (Ubuntu 22.04 spinoff) on an Apple Macbookpro7,1. I'm attempting to record my screen to capture some content that updates every 200ms. So I don't need a terribly high framerate, but I would like nice fidelity of the text displayed, and I don't have a very large screen either. I feel like this should be doable.
My ffmpeg is built from source, with ./configure --enable-libxcb --enable-libpulse
and my command is ffmpeg -probesize 10M -video_size 1280x800 -framerate 10 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -f pulse -ac 2 -i default output.mp4
My problem is, with these relatively default settings and low demands, I find the quality isn't always good enough to clearly catch the updating text.
Could someone suggest a few changes to improve my video quality? I prefer to continue saving as MP4 unless that itself is the problem.
My recent video result is here: https://youtu.be/x4SJ7SfGsuc?si=ZpDfbmtnwKeLc3H_&t=25

Hey, you should probably choose the question to ask. You're asking two, and this site requires a single question per post, so you should remove the secondary question. Feel free to make another post with that question. Second, what research have you done regarding this, and have you tried any other arguments in ffmpeg?

agreed, done.
I removed "Now I have two problems... the mouse cursor is not showing and I wish that it would... this problem I can live with, but I thought I would mention it in case the problems might be related."
